# Unhappy dweller due to unseen corpse

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have unhappy dwellers in one of my power plants due to a corpse that is no longer there. I didn't revive the corpse, I just buried it instead and now they are unhappy.

I have moved them to other rooms and back. I have removed them and put completely new dwellers in the power plant and still they are unhappy. What can I do?

Comment: Maybe try to demolish the room and rebuild it?

Comment: How long has this been going on? Have you exited to the main menu and reinitialized the vault yet?

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Happened several times to me and the only option was to destroy/rebuild the room. It's hopefully fixed with the latest release (1.4)

Answer (score 1):

When they are depressed, send them to a bedroom for a break. Wait until their happiness gets over 50% and they have a slight smile. Then put them back to work. They should go up to 75%.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the games code since release.

The only way I know to fix this is to remove the room and replace it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to pull the dweller out and put them into another room then try and look for the corpse in the empty room if you cant see it anywhere at all demo the room then replace it then put the dweller back. It should be fixed then. I haven't run into the problem really but there was a version of it where I had a dead dweller that was glitched in the room and couldnt remove him and the moral of the others was constantly declining so I moved them then removed the room and replaced it then moved them back. It seemed to work. But this glitch has happened 3 times on my phone for some reason.