# My dwellers aren't happy

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've assigned them with the right job and I've revived dead dwellers, but still all of them are saying "oh a corpse, isn't that pleasant.."

What should I do? All dwellers are alive, water, food, and all the bars are green. All of them are healthy.

Comment: Probably duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/253596/108003

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This appears similar to a previously reported problem of dwellers complaining about an invisible corpse. The other question never received a good answer. Have you tried exiting and restarting the app?

Answer (score 1):

Tap the vault button at the top left corner of the screen, then check the list for any dead dwellers. There is a chance that they died "outside" the room boundaries.